# We got $x \cdot f\left (\frac {x} {2} \right) - f\left (\frac {2} {x} \right) = 1$? Can you find all $f : \mathbb {R} _0 \to \mathbb{R} $

Tags: functions

Hello We got $x \cdot f\left (\frac {x} {2} \right) - f\left (\frac {2} {x} \right) = 1$? Can you find all $f : \mathbb {R} _0 \to \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: Welcome to MSA.  You'll find simple question statements rarely get much positive attention here.   If you put down what you understand about the problem/what you've tried so far,  you'll get far better responses

Comment: I tried but didn't get anything that can be useful

Comment: What is meaning of subscript $0$ on domain of $f$ ?

Comment: Does the $0$ subscript just mean $0$ has been removed from the reals for the domain?

Comment: Yes so we don't divide by 0

Comment: @zwim Whoops, yes I did.

Comment: Soo'? No one got an idea ?

Comment: Hint: substitute $x$ by $\frac 1x$ then solve the resulting system of two equations and two unknown (i.e. call $u=f(x)$ and $v=f(\frac 1x)$ and find $u,v$).

Comment: I get$ \frac{1}{x}.f(\frac{1}{2x})-f(2x)=1$

Comment: And the first equation it doesn't make anything because we don't have the same variables in the system

Comment: OK, start from $2xf(x)-f(\frac 1x)=1$...

Comment: U just put that x=2x whis is equivalent to x=0 and this is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$. Then, by plugging in $x$ and $\frac4x$ into the functional equation, we have

$$1 = x f\left(\frac{x}2\right) - f\left(\frac2x\right) = \frac4x f\left(\frac2x\right) - f\left(\frac{x}2\right).$$

In particular, by isolating the "$f\left(\frac{x}2\right)$ terms" on one side and the "$f\left(\frac2x\right)$ terms" on the other side, we obtain

$$(x+1)\cdot f\left(\frac{x}2\right) = \frac{x+4}x \cdot f\left(\frac2x\right).$$

For $x = -4$, it follows that $f(-2) = 0$.

For $x \neq -4$, we have

$$f\left(\frac2x\right) = \frac{x(x+1)}{x+4} \cdot f\left(\frac{x}2\right).$$

Substituting back into the original functional equation, we obtain that

$$1 = \frac{3x}{x+4} \cdot f\left(\frac{x}2\right) \ \ \ \ \ \text{ for each } x \neq 0, -4.$$

Hence, after replacing $x$ by $2x$,

$$f(x) = \frac{x+2}{3x}.$$

Note that this solution is also defined at $-2$ and gives the desired value $f(-2) = 0$.